# Scale Set with custom image from another subscription

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-rm-template

I created a scale set with **managed disks** and a custom image (something like `/subscriptions/<SUB-ID>/resourceGroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/my-base-image`) and also an ARM template to deploy a new scale set with this custom image.
The template deployment works fine if I deploy to the same subscription where my custom image is located. But it fails when I try to deploy it to another subscription - even if these two subscription are part of the same tenant/directory and the user has access to both subscriptions.

*So am I right that it's not possible to use a custom image from a different subscription?*

If yes: it would be ok (not best solution, but ok), if I could copy the custom image from subscription A to subscription B - But I can't see a way to copy this ressource. I think the only way is to recreate everything and use **unmanged disks**, because here I can download and upload the .vhd file from/to the storage account.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, Azure doesn’t support move a managed Image to anther subscription .But, this function will come soon. Also , I supply a way for this issue.

1. Create a temporary VM in A subscription using your Image.
2. Move this temporary VM to B subscription.
3. Capture a new Image and delete the temporary VM.

Then, you can use this image to do what you want to do.

NOTE: Moving a VM to another subscription is very easy. You just need to click Move button on VM’s overview in portal.

Also, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583940/create-azure-vm-from-image-created-under-different-subscription) supply another solution and it may be helpful to your case.

Comment: Can you tell what "soon" means? ;-) And if I would use **unmanaged** disks instead, would I be able to use a custom vhd URI with a scale set in another subscription?

Comment: Hi,@Munchkin . 

1.Move image to another subscription is a great function we want to realize. And we are devoting ourselves to this .But I cannot tell you the time when this function can be online.

2.You can use VHD URI from different subscription to create VMs.

Comment: Hi,@Munchkin, If this answer is helpful to you ,please mark it as answer to help more people. Thanks!

Comment: I have two additional questions: 1) Will it also be possible to **copy** a managed Image to another subscription? 2) Can I create a .vhd from a managed image?